# Slick slider margin issues lazyYT

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I am using lazyYT to load youtube video's faster. The loaded lazyYT videos are then placed in the slick slider. What then happens is that the video's are sticking together instead of a nice margin between every video. So I manually added a class to the video div

```
<div class="js-lazyYT" id="video-slide" data-youtube-id="<?php echo $video['video_link']; ?>" data-width="500" data-height="425"></div>
```

and gave it a margin which is working fine until the first video comes loaded back again. They paste together until all three first video's are visible again.

```
#video-slide{
    width: 500px !important;
    height: 425px !important;
    margin-right: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

[image]

[image]

It looks like the first 3 entries in the slider reload the slider again when they are visible. Any idea?

```
;(function ($) {
    'use strict';

    function setUp($el) {
        var width = $el.data('width'),
            height = $el.data('height'),
            ratio = $el.data('ratio'),
            id = $el.data('youtube-id'),
            aspectRatio = ['16', '9'],
            paddingTop = 0,
            youtubeParameters = $el.data('parameters') || '';

        if (typeof width === 'undefined' || typeof height === 'undefined') {
          height = 0;
          width = '100%';
          aspectRatio = (ratio.split(":")[1] / ratio.split(":")[0]) * 100;
          paddingTop = aspectRatio + '%';
        }

        $el.css({
            'position': 'relative',
            'height': height,
            'width': width,
            'padding-top': paddingTop,
            'background': 'url(http://img.youtube.com/vi/' + id + '/hqdefault.jpg) center center no-repeat',
            'cursor': 'pointer',
            'background-size': 'cover'
        })
            .html('<p id="lazyYT-title-' + id + '" class="lazyYT-title"></p><div class="lazyYT-button"></div>')
            .addClass('lazyYT-image-loaded');

        $.getJSON('https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' + id + '?v=2&alt=json', function (data) {
            $('#lazyYT-title-' + id).text(data.entry.title.$t);
        });

        $el.on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (!$el.hasClass('lazyYT-video-loaded') && $el.hasClass('lazyYT-image-loaded')) {
                $el.html('<iframe width="' + width + '" height="' + height + '" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/' + id + '?autoplay=1&' + youtubeParameters + '" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%;" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>')
                    .removeClass('lazyYT-image-loaded')
                    .addClass('lazyYT-video-loaded');
            }
        });

    }

    $.fn.lazyYT = function () {
        return this.each(function () {
            var $el = $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
            setUp($el);
        });
    };

}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Is there any other styling that might be colliding with what you show? Have you played with display: inline vs block vs inline-block?

Comment: No not at all, since it normally loads images and with lazyYT it basically loads images too so didn't need to change.

Comment: So far I have found out that the divs that are cloned loose the id of video-slide until they are loaded into the slider completely.

Comment: Can you show us that part of the code? You might also be able to add an id to all video elements in your holder div - $('holder video').attr('id', 'video-slide');

Comment: Sorry to just mention it, but I already fixed it with that before, thanks anyway! The only problem left is that the youtube titles won't load of those as shown in pic 1, ill post the code.

Comment: From this page - https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters - I wonder if you have the 'showinfo' parameter set to '1'.

Comment: I think like there is something else playing. I just noticed I can't start playing the ones without title either!

Comment: So there probably is a larger issue here. I think I might go "back-to-basics", minimize your code and slowly add stuff in until you see the bug, or have a solution.

Comment: I actually think it is an issue within slick slider. I will work on it some more, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking at the lazyYT site and found their example:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="js-lazyYT" data-youtube-id="_oEA18Y8gM0" data-width="560" data-height="315" data-parameters="rel=0"></div>
</div>
```

Given that, you might try:

```
.myclass {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

    <div class="container">
       <div class="js-lazyYT myclass" data-youtube-id="_oEA18Y8gM0" data-width="560" data-height="315" data-parameters="rel=0"></div>
    </div>
```

or

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="js-lazyYT" data-youtube-id="_oEA18Y8gM0" data-width="560" data-height="315" data-parameters="rel=0"> style='margin-left: 5px'</div>
</div>
```

or

```
.myclass div {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

<div class="container myclass">
   <div class="js-lazyYT" data-youtube-id="_oEA18Y8gM0" data-width="560" data-height="315" data-parameters="rel=0"></div>
</div>
```